# send messages to service with a call to startService

Tags: android, android-service

I've create a service and I'm accessing it via my activity using `bindService` function but I wanted to keep running my service even after my activity exited.

And for that I've to use `startService` but previously I was using `bindService` with a `ServiceConnection` where I'm sending message to the `handler` (in a service) once the `onServiceConnected` gets called.

But I don't know how can I send message with a `startService` as I don't have any place like `onServiceConnected` to send the message to the handler.

*note: I want to keep running my service even I'm out of my application as I'm updating widget from my service.*

so a service has two roles

1. update textview inside activity
2. once the activity exits , service will update widget

Comment: How do you start your service, i mean u might be using an intent to start your service right?

Comment: Yes as i wanted to keep running in background i am using `startService`

Comment: Ok, then have what you exactly want to sent to your service? you can send it through same intent which u have used to start service. Have you tried doing that?

Comment: Oh! sorry. I think i just misinterpreted your problem ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 3 option to communicate with your service:

- Put an extra to the intent and call startService. You can call it
  several times, even if the service is already running
- Create a Messenger and use it to communicate with the service
- Use bindService

Be sure to use `START_STICKY` in your service so it keeps running after yhe activity finishes, and `startForeground()` to show a notification or your service will be killed by SO after some time (in average, 30 minutes to 1 hour).

**Starting flow:**

- ClientActivity (CA) starts the service and sends the CA Messenger address as an extra in the intent to the service.
- On service start it sends the service Messenger address back to the
  CA (using the CA Messenger address to send the message).
- Finally, service returns START_STICKY.

With this both, client and server will know each other Messenger addresses and no bind is required.

**To stop service:**

To stop the service use the follwoing in your activity:

```
stopService(new Intent(ActivityClass.this, ServiceClass.class));
```

**Reconnection:**

If you leave the clieant activity (CA) and want to reconnect to service when app is restarted, you have two options:

-Call startService again from your CA. This will call again the `onStartCommand` in the service. The service `onCreate()` is called only if the service is not yet running. You can use the starting flow described above to get the service Messenger;

-You can make the service Messenger public and static `public static Messenger mMsgService = null;`. So, when your CA starts, it can check whether service messenger has been initialized (not null) and use it to communicate with the service. When setvice stops, need to set `mMsgService = null;`

good luck.

Comment: As i am using `Messenger` to register client and fetching values so first option wont work. but to send message to the service and receive it in a activity i got to use `bindService` but when i exist i got to `unBindService` and the service stops

Comment: When you start the service you can send the client Messenger address as an extra in the intent to the service. On service start you send the service Messenger address back to the client (using the client Messenger address to send the message). Finally you return START_STICKY from service start to keep it running. With this both, client and server will know each other Messenger addresses and no bind is required.

Comment: i tried your approach but as soon as i leave the activity and come back into application i lost the service Messenger Address and thus i am not be able to stop the service.

Comment: and i tried calling `stopService` to stop service once i come back into activity for the second time but the service didnt stop

Comment: To stop the service use: stopService(new Intent(ActivityClass.this, ServiceClass.class)); . I'm using it in several apps without any problem.

Comment: If you leave app and then want to reconnect to service you have two options. I'll edit answer to include them.

Comment: yeah i did that only but once i leave the activity and come back into the same activity service is not getting stopped dont know why

Comment: I´ve edited my answer in some more detail. My service `onDestroy()` is just calling `super.ondestroy()` and clean all services resources. It never failed me :-) Jus as a hint, are you using runnables or sleeps in the service? You may need to release all of them to have the service finishing.

Comment: BTW +1 for your interest and meaningful answer

Comment: So, in the service onDestroy, terminate your threads and call super.onDestroy().

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way to communicate to a Service other than binding to that service. Binding the service in an activity doesn't necessarity mean that the Service will be(or need to be) unbinded onDestroy of the service. If you don't call the unbindService method, then the binded Service will be running always. So the solution is  bind to the Service and don't call unbindService onDestroy of the activity.

Comment: Will i get `Service Leak Exception` if i dont unbind it ?

Comment: no you won't get it if you start the service with Application context

Comment: even if i pass `this.getApplicationContext()` i do get `android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.ha.home.MyActivity` has leaked `ServiceConnection com.ha.home.MyActivity$1@448163e8` that was originally bound here